# css inner border, broken layout

Tags: css, border, border-layout

I have divided the screen with many `div` so they stick one to each other (let say, something like chess-board, but with fields of variable sizes). I set `heigth` and `width` using percents (relative to parent container).

Now, when I add `border: 1px` to the divs, all the layout breaks... I imagine that the border adds 1px to each side, and the solution would be to add some *internal* border. Can I add somehow such an internal border?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) to make the border's width part of the `width` of the element.

```css
.example {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Browser support.](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)

Comment: /* You forgot -ms for IE*/
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing:     border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;

Comment: @EmilioYero: No, I didn't. Take a look at the "browser support" link at the end of my answer. IE7 doesn't support it at all, whereas IE8 and higher support it without a vendor prefix.

Answer (score 5):

Use outline property. Unlike the border propperty it does not "add" to the height or width of the elements. However also unlike the border propeerty you can not have left, right, bottom or left individual properties. Although you can have outline-style, outline-width and outline-color properties.

[Outline Refrence](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/bordersoutlines)

Comment: @Phil: I am not sure, but I think outline property is well supported even in legacy browsers. I stand to be corrected.

Comment: @thirtydot: One thing I found out using CSS reference is that their comptibility department is often wrong. For example I have from personal experience that outline is suppoted in IE8 and above and in FF 3.5 and above.

Comment: That link says "buggy" for IE8 and FF 3.5. That means it *does work*, but.. there are bugs which are detailed underneath the compatibility table.

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the percentages by `0.5` making them `49.5%` EDIT: Outset won't work, thanks @thirty

Comment: `outset` won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let say, if you have a parent div and many child divs. When you set the height and width as percentages, you'll get them stick to each other. Then when adding `border:1px` their width will become longer than as it was before. To solve this, I would say that you should have `another div after the parent div` to prevent resizing width.

Comment: @Jawad: try to remove both `padding` and `margin` then it would wrap all the child divs together.